# Generate a word document from a simple form

Tags: javascript

I am trying to modify a word document with data retrieved via a form without success. Please help me. My code manages to retrieve the data from the form when I look in the console but no file is downloaded.

My form:

```
<form id="myForm">

        <label for="name">Nom:</label>

        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="John"><br>

        <label for="email">Email:</label>

        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="john@example.com"><br>

       

        <button id="generate">Générer le document</button>

    </form>
```

JS file:

```
<script

 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/docxtemplater/3.39.1/docxtemplater.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/pizzip@3.1.4/dist/pizzip.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/pizzip@3.1.4/dist/pizzip-utils.js"></script>

    <script>

        function loadFile(url, callback) {

            PizZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, callback);

        }


window.generate = function generate() {

    // Récupérer le formulaire par son ID

    const form = document.getElementById('myForm');

    

    // Utiliser FormData pour obtenir les données du formulaire

    const formData = new FormData(form);

    

    // Convertir les données du formulaire en un objet JavaScript

    const data = {};

    formData.forEach((value, key) => {

        data[key] = value;

    });

    console.log("Données du formulaire:", data); // Afficher les données extraites du formulaire

    loadFile(

        "doc.docx",

        function (error, content) {

            if (error) {

                console.error("Erreur lors du chargement du fichier doc.docx:", error); // Afficher les erreurs de chargement

                return;

            }

            const zip = new PizZip(content);

            const doc = new window.docxtemplater(zip, {

                paragraphLoop: true,

                linebreaks: true,

            });

            // Rendre le document avec les données du formulaire

            doc.render(data);

            const blob = doc.getZip().generate({

                type: "blob",

                mimeType:

                    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",

                compression: "DEFLATE",

            });

            // Enregistrer le document avec un nom basé sur le nom saisi dans le formulaire

            saveAs(blob, "Contrat_" + data.name + ".docx");

        }

    );

};
</script>
```

I have a form containing several fields.  I want to be able to use form fields to fill out a word document template.  My code doesn't seem to work, I can't generate the word file.

Comment: How does the button link to the function? I see no click or submit event listeners

Comment: the binding between the button and the function is done using window.generate

Comment: There is no event listener in that code. So I really have no idea how that button is calling `generate()` or `window.generate()`